# Pentary Search Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relation, average-case

I have done an assignment question which asks me to find the average case of pentary search. The one I came up with is:

```
C(n) = C(n/5) + 14/5
```

However, I got it wrong and the professor didn't really explain why.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Edit:

Pentary search is dividing the array into 5 parts and look for a specific key.

In perspective:

1|2|3|4|4

These are the number of comparisons made by the computer from pentary search.

Adding all possible comparisons I get 14 over 5 slots. This is why I have 14/5

Comment: I think a minimal explanation (i.e. "what is pentary search") might help.

Comment: Edited, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one thing that could be wrong with your recurrence, depending on how exactly the algorithm is stated: you are overlooking the case that the element could be found before recursion.

Comment: 1. That makes sense.

2. So is it 14/4?

Comment: I get something else. Don't guess, compute the average number of comparisons. You can use the formula for expectation if you're not sure how to.

Comment: Hmm, that'll be tricky. I left an explanation as to why I got 14/5 as an edit.

Comment: Ok, I guess you're right and I made a mistake... (The previous version of my answer erroneously claimed that the average number of comparisons has to be of the form $X/4$ instead of $X/5$.)

Comment: I'm right on the edit or the second previous comment?

Comment: Right on your edit.

Comment: Oh, ok. Now, regarding the part where the element is found before the recurstion: does that add or subtract one from the expected value?

Comment: Well, if you find the element, you don't need to recurse.

Comment: Still 14/5, gotcha.